# Open source SAR data for the year 1999-2001 over India

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uses-of-open-data, historical

where I can get Radarsat-1 data for 1999-2001 over Indian region(open for download)?
or can anyone suggest me SAR dataset for the above mentioned year and location which can be downloaded free of cost.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not found one yet,

Here is the link to it

https://earth.esa.int/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/r/radarsat-1